# How to restore previous state of angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I need to keep controllers' state in angular ,for improving some user experiences, during user is visiting different pages.

For instance I have a list, which is created via a directive, and it has a pagination section, so imagine when a user go to page 20 and choose an item, they'll be redirected to the detail page, but when they click back button and return to the previous page they see the first page of the list which is not convenient and they expect to be on page 20 again.

I've come up with several options:

1. Using a dialog to display second page (item detail), so they can close that    modal and return to the previous form without any change.
2. Redirecting users to the second page with a parameter in URL and then return them with that parameter to understand what page number they have been before.
3. Keeping some crucial variable globally to store controller state and using them when user comes back.

But I think there should be better ideas like keeping controllers' state during redirection.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Option 2 with or without (if data is updated frequently) caching of the data in a service is my preferred method usually.

Comment: Google ui router extras sticky states

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Redirecting users to the second page with a parameter in URL and then return them with that parameter to understand what page number they have been before.

I prefer this because you get the added benefit of staying on page 20 when you do a page refresh. Options 1 and 3 do not give you this added benefit. Path params are also bookmark friendly.

Another alternative for you to look into that is almost as good is [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
or cookies. I dont think these options are better than your 2 though.

Comment: Can you please show some example how can we implement this using angular jS route provider